# iOS Application will not run after deleting all users

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my backend in a Swift Application. I went through my data and deleted all my users to start over while a there was currently a current PFUser. Now when I go to run the application it gives me this error.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
```

this is the line of code it goes to

```
let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
```

the debugger also says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0X0)

This is odd because in my `override func viewDidAppear` I have code to check is PFUSers is nil and then to open my signup or login UIAlertController.

Any solutions? Is this a common issue? 
Let me know if you need additional information.

**Solution**

I deleted all the posts in the data base as well because the program was trying to load the stored posts that had no user object.

Comment: It looks like `(objects as NSArray)` is `nil`, so you're getting an error when you try calling lastObject on it.

Comment: I actually figured it out! I deleted all the posts in the data base as well because the program was trying to load the stored posts that had no user object. Works fine now!  This actually helped thanks a ton Brian!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to uninstall the app, so that the current user registered in the app and managed by parse is deleted locally.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to uninstall the app, I havent put it on a device just xcode simulator

Comment: Yeah all I had to do was delete all the posts that had the old users i deleted and the app ran fine after.

Comment: To uninstall the app, tap and hold on the app icon in the simulator (or device) until icons start to shake, then click the `x` button. Alternatively, you can reset the simulator from menu iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings